# Pandas: Groupby count as column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

[image]

I would like to generate counts instances of 'x' (regardless of whether they're unique, or not) per 'id'. The result would be insert as a column labeled 'x_count' as shown below:

[image]

Any tips would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply a groupby with transform `count`

```
df['x_count'] = df.groupby('id')['x'].transform('count')
```

If you also want to count the `NaN`, use `size'

```
df['x_count'] = df.groupby('id')['x'].transform('size')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `.value_counts` with `.map`

```
df['x_count'] = df['id'].map(df.value_counts('id'))
```